# Openfire Sending Push notification when user is offline

Tags: openfire

I am using openfire 3.9.3 server and Android and IOS as client.
I want to send messages via push notification to both clients when recipient user is offline. 
And when push is sent sender should get message receipt.

for this, i tried :

1. making interceptor: In this, i didn't get any exception or message failure for which i can track.
2. modify openfire code also. But i don't think it is a good solution.

I just want to know that, is there any plugin for it or modifying the openfire code is the last solution for it?

Comment: have you got answer for this ?

Comment: yes i made interceptor for it and it is working now. thanx

Comment: have u made interceptor in java ? it can possible in c#?

Comment: Can you please provide some more details on this? I have exactly similar requirement.

Comment: @VishalShukla you will need to create your own custom plugin for it.

Comment: @Rahul can you please provide some more details regarding plugin development, i am stuck with it.

Comment: @Rahul If you are sending push notification to person to person you should try CallbackOnOffline plugin instead of plugin development.

https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins.jsp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I got the answer after searching and reading docs..

Openfire provides custom plugin support. So I created my own plugin for it that supports this feature.

[Here](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) is a better step-by-step explanation for openfire plugin development.

In brief,

after building openfire source and creating openfire plugin structure as per the [doc](https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html).

1. Implement openfire Plugin interface,
2. Put an entry for your plugin class in plugin.xml,
3. Put your db in database folder,
4. Initialize your interceptors in your plugin classes.
5. Build it with ant tool.
6. Upload your generated jar in your openfire plugins list via admin panel.

Comment: Hey Rahul, it its possible for you then please cna you share that plugin ?

Comment: Can you please share this plug-in with us?  It will be great!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Rahul,
Can you please share that plug-in with us if possible?