# Can I Customize Openfire to use as MBaaS for mobile push notification? How?

Tags: android, push-notification, xmpp, openfire, prosody-im

I decide to build an infrastructure to send push notification using XMPP Protocol. 
I don't want to use 3rd party services like GCM or FCM [because [Google restricts FCM service based on IP Address, Is there any other free Android push notification provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41776992/google-restricts-fcm-service-based-on-ip-address) ]. i don't want to use Ejabberd either because it has some cost. i have a plan to configure Openfire on my server with SQL Server so that when a message body with particular recipient(s), added to database somehow, Openfire sends those to proper client(s) [push notification to android devices].

I am developing an XMPP client on Android to connect with this server. i think it doesn't matter what platform i'm working on, anyway it's Android.

can i send message (push notification) from server to client(s) with Openfire? How?

If not, how about Prosody or other XMPP servers?

I appriciate any help

Comment: Look if it's a good solution for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819146/android-smack-keep-xmpp-connection-alive-in-sleep-mode

Comment: I think i am not clear things enough in my question. i don't want chat application. i want one way transfer of message and i want it delivered in any situation whether app is in foreground or background. it is a push notification definition.               َ                                                    According to Wikipedia these software do not support push notification. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_XMPP_server_software

Comment: I know, but if you follow the solution provided by Flow you'll be able with pubsub feature or simply with broadcast messages to simulate the push notification without write tons of code.

Comment: is that all? i just need to setup Openfire and Smack. since there is no detail on that page, how do they implement BOSH? is it a plugin for Openfire? a message should be send by server(push notification), what's the message sender's ID(JID)?                                                                Thank you

Comment: BOSH it's "free" in Openfire (https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/54304). About service user to generate the messages you can choose to create a default user (easy way) or develop a plugin to intercept packet of a certain type without "sender". Client side you'll just ignore the sender and you'll fetch the XML and display as you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i think it would work. this is another link for this issue:         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714651/openfire-sending-push-notification-when-user-is-offline/34413295#34413295